# How to remove extra paths of nested modules from URL Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a **nested module** structure. And right now I'm accessing the pages like this

**when click on a post to read or update**

localhost:4200/single-post/63846ef2f20c6912e128f604?id=63846ef2f20c6912e128f604

localhost:4200/update/63846ef2f20c6912e128f604?id=63846ef2f20c6912e128f604

**I want to remove `single-post` and `update` from my URLs and want to show the URLs like this**

```
localhost:4200/63846ef2f20c6912e128f604?id=63846ef2f20c6912e128f604
```

**Following is the Current Code structure**

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => PagesModule,
  },
```

**pages-routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: 'posts',
    loadChildren: () => PostsModule,
  },
```

**posts-routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: 'update/:id', loadChildren: () => UpdateModule },

{ path: 'single-post/:id', loadChildren: () => ReadSinglePostModule },
```

**when click on read button**

```
 this.route.navigate([`single-post/${id}`], {
      queryParams: { id: id },
    });
```

**when click on update button**

```
 this.route.navigate([`update/${id}`], {
      queryParams: { id: id },
    });
```

Comment: You can use just the :id in the path and then use CanMatch https://angular.io/api/router/CanMatch to match the update / reading module. You would also have to pass info the guard vie data or query params so that it knows whether it is a update / read request.

Comment: I don't have guards for the routes right now. But I got your point. Isn't there any other way to do it without guards? A quick and a simple way for a simple app